# Unwanted line shift

Tags: poetry

How do I get rid of the unwanted line shift between the second and third line?

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\usepackage{verse}
\PassOptionsToPackage{bookmarks, colorlinks=false, hidelinks}{hyperref}
% Use PoetryTeX; http://www.ctan.org/pkg/poetrytex
\usepackage[numberpoems, clearpageafterpoem, useincipits]{poetrytex}

% Use the PA5 paper size
\usepackage[paperwidth=140mm,paperheight=210mm]{geometry}



\begin{document}


\begin{poem}{~}

    \poemtitle{Poem name}
    \settowidth{\versewidth}{And objects at rest tended to remain at rest tended to remain at rest}

    \begin{verse}[\versewidth]
        This is the first line\\
        \mbox{The second line is much longer than the first} \\
        \mbox{The third has unwanted space from the second}
    \end{verse} 

\end{poem}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I'm not sure whether this is also true for your input file, but after the last line (just after the closing brace) there was an invisible character U+2028 that you should remove if it's in your file, too.

Comment: After \end{document}?

Comment: No, after `\mbox{The third has unwanted space from the second}` (I removed it from your MWE).

Comment: There is no such character there with me.

Comment: If you don't already, try compiling with pdfLaTeX once and see whether it complains about that U+2028 character, if it doesn't it really just somehow crept in during copying/editing in the browser, else it is in your file (as I said, it's invisible, some editors might display it as a space or similar, some might hide it completely).

Comment: I always compile with pdfLaTeX, I think, and in this case I do not get an error message.

Comment: Although the answer resetting the width obviously works, I would try removing the space before the `\\ ` on the second line, after the `\mbox`.  Since that line is longer than the default width, the space would cause that line to go to a second output line.

Comment: That doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that your lines are too long for A5 paper, so either let `verse` do its job and remove the `\mbox`, or lie properly about the length of a line:

```latex
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\usepackage{verse}
\PassOptionsToPackage{bookmarks, colorlinks=false, hidelinks}{hyperref}
% Use PoetryTeX; http://www.ctan.org/pkg/poetrytex
\usepackage[numberpoems, clearpageafterpoem, useincipits]{poetrytex}

% Use the PA5 paper size
\usepackage[paperwidth=140mm,paperheight=210mm]{geometry}



\begin{document}


\begin{poem}{~}

    \poemtitle{Poem name}
    \settowidth{\versewidth}{And objects at rest tended to remain at rest tended to remain at rest}

    \begin{verse}[\versewidth]
        This is the first line\\
        \makebox[\linewidth][l]{The second line is much longer than the first} \\
        \makebox[\linewidth][l]{The third has unwanted space from the second}
    \end{verse} 

\end{poem}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! I think I would like to use a4 format. Is it easy to swich?

Comment: @Sapiens just use `\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}` instead of your `geometry` line.

Comment: Thanks for that! :)